# How can i get 'Captured Amount' and 'Refunded Amount' in Shopify API

Tags: shopify

I'm unable to find amount that was captured after the authorization.

Also when I cancel the order and refund partially, then too I do not get the amount that was refunded.

In `[Orders API][1]` of this transactions I only find is net amount, Shipping amt, Tax amt, Discount amt of the product, But no where I can see `Captured amount` or `Refunded amount`

Is there any way I can get the `Captured amount` or `Refunded amount` using API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [Transactions API](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/transaction) for that kind of information.